# Change content dynamically when my module cron runs

Tags: javascript, drupal-7, cron

I have a module named `my_module` and it uses for running cron. I am using hook_cron() to run cron in my module. I want to change the value of a javascript veriable when cron runs. This javascript variable has already present in the footer. I am using drupal 7. Can any one help me to write codes for this?

Answer (score 0):

This code can get you started.

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_cron()
*/
function [YOUR_MODULE]_cron() {
    variable_set('YOUR_VARIABLE', 'change this value to your liking');
}

/**
* Implementation of hook_init()
*/
function [YOUR_MODULE]_init() {
    $yourVariable = variable_get('YOUR_VARIABLE', '');
    drupal_add_js(array('YOUR_VARIABLE' => $yourVariable), 'setting');
}
```

Then in your javascript:

```
var myVar = Drupal.settings.YOUR_VARIABLE;
```

Docs:

- [`hook_init()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_init/7)
- [`hook_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7)
- [`variable_get()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7)
- [`variable_set()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7)

Comment: I tried the following code to pass PHP veriable, but the variable is not available in JS file. drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('key' => 'value')), 'setting'); I added js using drupal_add_js($GLOBALS['base_url'].'/'.drupal_get_path('module', 'myModule').'/js/test.js', array('type' => 'external'));

Comment: Did you include `drupal_add_js` inside `hook_init`? What do you use `drupal_add_js($GLOBALS['base_url'].'/'.drupal_get_path('module', 'myModule').'/js/test.js', array('type' => 'external'));` for?